# What percentage completion can be achieved without optional mission goals?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

If one did everything, but somehow avoided doing all the optional mission objectives: what completion percentage would they have by the end?

Comment: Avoiding *all* the optional mission objectives seems impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played this game thrice (probably my favorite  game). It is going to end up around 45.6%. in main quests , sometime you have to complete some side quest to proceed
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look in [howlongtobeat.com](https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=12707&s=completions) we can estimate that if you stick just with main missions you will end the game with around ~50%.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @Joachim, checking howlongtobeat.com, there is notes beside each entry, sometimes users add the percentage, base on that and with my own experience (but I can not say that I did just only the main quest but also some side quests and got 56%), so based on that was possible to estimate but not say exactly.